# C:\WINDOWS\System32 vs C:\Windows\System32

Tags: microsoft, system32

Just an out of interest question I think - in task manager some file locations are C:\WINDOWS\System32 and some are in C:\Windows\System32.

How come there is a change of case?

Comment: Those two paths are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does not normally care about Folder or File case.

Certainly not for System32, so this is no cause for any worry or alarm.

A User or an App may change the case.

Just carry on.

Comment: Great thank you!